# Printing out nested dictionary in specific format and outputting to json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x, dictionary, d3.js

I'm trying to print out a dictionary in the following format. I want to do this because I need to graph some trends in D3 using the JSON format. For this trend, I am counting the number of murders in each state within each decade (1980s to 2010s).

I am able to output the file and everything but since I am trying to create a graph, the format of the data in the JSON file needs to be very specific in terms of labeling each key, value pair in the dictionary in the output.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('Murders.xlsx')
df = xl.parse('Sheet1')
year = df['Year']
state = df['State']
freq = dict()

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    currYear = year.iloc[i]
    if(currYear >= 1980 and currYear < 1989):
        currDecade = 1980
    elif(currYear >= 1990 and currYear < 2000):
        currDecade = 1990
    elif(currYear >= 2000 and currYear < 2010):
        currDecade = 2000
    elif(currYear >= 2010):
        currDecade = 2010
    currState = state.iloc[i]
    if currDecade in freq:
        if currState in freq[currDecade]:
            freq[currDecade][currState] += 1
        else:
            key = {currState: 1}
            freq[currDecade].update(key)
    else:
        key = {currDecade:{currState: 1}}
        freq.update(key)

#print(freq)

file = open("MurderRateDecState.js", "w+")
file.write(json.dumps(freq))
file.close()
```

I expect the output to be [{"Decade": "1980", "State": [{"State": "California", "Freq": 29591}, {"State": "Massachusetts", "Freq": 1742}, ...}]

However I am getting {"1980": {"Wyoming": 245, "Alaska": 533}, etc..

This is the xlsx file I am working with [image: Murders.xlsx]

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the way you're handling the freq variable.

```
key = {currDecade:{currState: 1}}
```

That would translate to something like:

```
{"1980":{"California":1}}
```

If you change that line and the other branches to something like this you should get the output you were expecting.

```
{currDecade:{"State":currState, "Freq":1}}
```

Comment: That actually does not give me the expected output.